# Close rx stream basing on amount of passed data by another stream

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have an infinite stream:

`someIntStream: Observable<Int>`

and I'd like to expose a function with following signature:

`fun retrieveInts(numberOfIntsToRetrieve: Int): Observable<Int>`

, which should emit exactly the same items as `someIntStream`, but it should emit `OnCompleted` once it emits `numberOfIntsToRetrieve` ints. My solution:

```
fun retrieveInts(numberOfIntsToRetrieve: Int): Observable<Int> {
    val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    val ints = mutableListOf<Int>()
    return Observable.create() { emitter ->
        compositeDisposable.add(
            someIntStream().subscribe { someIntItem ->
                ints.add(someIntItem)
                emitter.onNext(someIntItem)
                if (ints.size == numberOfIntsToRetrieve) {
                    emitter.onComplete()
                    compositeDisposable.dispose()
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

But it's nasty: I have to internally subscribe to stream and dispose it.
Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you simply need `take` on the infinite source.

Comment: Yep, I think this should resolve my issue. Thanks akarnokd.